# Offical signed certificate is not accepted from curl via repository commit

Tags: certificate, repository

I have a signed certificate installed on my server. It is working fine, with the webserver. But if I am trying to commit something to a repository, I get the following error message:

```
   Warning: post-commit hook failed (exit code 60) with output:
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time
Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left
Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--
    0curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

I updated curl, checked the permissions and the certificates, I checked also the path, but I could not detect a mistake.

Does someone has an idea, what I need to to, to get this fixed?

(The hostos is SMP Debian 3.2.65-1)

Thanks in advance

most sincerely

Twinhand

Answer (score 1):

You'll either need to provide the entire cert chain to curl on the CLI or configure your server properly so that it sends the whole chain.

Comment: I dont see, how I can do that :/, also, why is my webserver not complaining about this .

Comment: Your webserver would not complain. Some clients would.

Comment: But as far as I heard no clients have had problems "complains" about this when accessing the website which is using the certificate. :/

Comment: @Twinhand curl is a client, and clearly it's having a problem with your cert chain. Not *all* clients will have this problem.

Comment: Hint: use `openssl s_client` to troubleshoot cert chain issues.